# java code, finding the min, max and average of floating point numbers

Tags: java

I wrote the below code everything works fine except it never executes the last loop so the last value inputted is never calculated into the min/max/average.
Any idea where I went wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program4_JohnHuber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

   double total = 0;
   //double numbers = 0;
   int count = 1;
   double largest = 0;
   double smallest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   double average = 0;

   System.out.print ("Please enter the grades, (Press enter when finished): ");
   {
       while (input.hasNextDouble()&& count<5)
       {
           double entered = input.nextDouble();
           total = total + entered;
           //count++;

       //double average = 0;
       if (count > 0)
       {
           average = total/count;
       }
       if (entered > largest)
       {
           largest = entered;
       }
       if (entered < smallest)
       {
           smallest = entered;
       }
       count++;
       }

   }
       System.out.printf ("Your average grade is %3.2f,\n", average);
       System.out.printf ("Your highest grade is %3.2f \n", largest);
       System.out.printf ("Your lowest grade is %3.2f \n", smallest);



}
}
```

Comment: How are you entering numbers? All on the same line?

Comment: either on the same line or enter after each number, it seems to drop which ever number is entered last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your program (assuming your intent is to input 5 numbers):

1. You're using `count` to indicate the number of grades you've entered already.  Before you've entered any grades, how many grades have you entered?  That's the value `count` should have, but you've initialized it to the wrong value.
2. The other issue is in how you've written the `while`:

   ```
      while (input.hasNextDouble() && count<5)
   ```

Suppose you've fixed the first problem, so that it now lets you enter 5 numbers and keeps statistics on those numbers.  Now it goes back up to the `while` loop and evaluates the boolean expression.

At this point, `count` is 5, so you want to exit the loop.  But that doesn't happen, because `input.hasNextDouble()` is evaluated **first**.  Since you're using a scanner on `System.in`, that means that the program waits until either you type in something that isn't blank, or until you indicate the end of input with CTRL+D on Linux or CTRL+Z on Windows.  **After** it finds the next item in the input, it will then exit the loop if it can't find a `double` (e.g. you type in some letters); or if you put in a `double`, **then** it checks `count`.

The combination of these two errors is why the program appears to be ignoring the last input: (1) it only does the computation on 4 grades, not 5, because of the error in initializing `count`, and (2) it asks for a 5th grade anyway, because the parts of the `while` loop condition are in the wrong order.

To fix the second problem, change it to

```
while (count < 5 && input.hasNextDouble())
```

This checks `count` *first*, and exits the loop immediately when you have enough grades, instead of looking for more input.

Comment: Thank you! I had the count = 0 then changed it to 1 to try and solve the last input dropping off. thank you again for your help and the kind explanation!